# Angular/Typescript RegExp enum

Tags: regex, angular, typescript

Looking to create an enum for some regex to store in my application to allow for code reuse.

Eg:

```
export enum Regex {
    ONE_DANK_REGEX = /^[dank]+$/g,
    FIVE_OUT_OF_SEVEN = /^[meme]{5,7}$/g
}
```

But:

1. By not using string literals, I get the TS90010 error: Type RegExpis not assignable to type Regex.
2. By using string literals, I can't use these in a pattern attribute on my inputs

Eg.

```
<input ngModel="..." pattern="{{FIVE_OUT_OF_SEVEN}}" .../>
```

Is this the right way of going about doing this?

Comment: Probably, `pattern="{{FIVE_OUT_OF_SEVEN.source}}"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew "Cannot read property 'source' of undefined" is thrown when the component is rendered :(

Comment: I also reeeeally don't want to create a form control instance just for a single field. Seems a bit over the top (as a side note)

Comment: Where/How is the variable `FIVE_OUT_OF_SEVEN` defined?

Comment: @Philipp - The FIVE_OUT_OF_SEVEN member is part of the Regex enum, for the purpose of this example, stored in a Regex.js file, in the folder of my Shared module. 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

Comment: @N15M0_jk But it is not visible within the component then. That's also why you got the `Cannot read property '...' of undefined` error.

Comment: @Philipp - that makes sense too, would you suggest something like importing the Regex enum in my .ts, bind the value to a variable and use that in my view?

Comment: @N15M0_jk - Exactly. I've prepared a demo, so you can see this in action. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ax9eph?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot assign a `RegExp` to an `enum`, an `enum` can either be numeric or string-based.

So when it comes to storing the `RegExp` you have two options:

**Option A** - store the `RegExp` as string in an enum

```
enum RegExpEnum {
    ONE_DANK_REGEX = "^[dank]+$",
    FIVE_OUT_OF_SEVEN = "^[meme]{5,7}$"
}
```

**Option B** - store the `RegExp` in a `class`/`variable`

```
class RegexClass {
    public static readonly ONE_DANK_REGEX = /^[dank]+$/g;
    public static readonly FIVE_OUT_OF_SEVEN = /^[meme]{5,7}$/g;
}
```

In both ways you need to get a reference to the containing `enum` or `class` in your component. Which can be achieved by assigning it to a local variable.

```
@Component({ ... })
public class MyComponent {
    availableRegex = RegExpEnum; // or RegexClass
}
```

Then you can access it in the html part of your component.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name" [pattern]="availableRegex.ONE_DANK_REGEX"/>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ax9eph)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed comment, but this is exactly what I ended up using. Thanks a ton @Philipp

Answer (score 1):

Enum will support only strings and Number.

If you wanted to store regular expressions, you need to use static class

```
export class RegularExpression
{
    public static ALPHA_CHARACTERS: RegExp = /([^A-Za-z])+/g;
}
```

**Usage**

```
'Your_* Name'.replace(RegularExpression.ALPHA_CHARACTERS, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefer the option A mentioned on the currently accepted answer and use it as below the code:

```
export enum Regex {
  ONE_DANK_REGEX = "^[dank]+$",
  FIVE_OUT_OF_SEVEN = "^[meme]{5,7}$",
}

public readonly regOne = new RegExp(Regex.ONE_DANK_REGEX, "g");
```

This gives some flexibility when create the regular expression object.